# GetX rootdelegate equivalent of Router.Neglect

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

There is a method in Router, Neglect, IIRC. it will not make a history on a browser when moving to the next page. Is there an equivalent of this in GetX routing ? I am having trouble in making sure user did not return to the OTP page using the built in web browser back button after inputing the OTP, since this caused some error

Comment: I am completely aware about the why not getX, however currently I am trying to fix someone else project whose whole architecture is using getX without needing to change the whole architecture